# Windows Update always start to download Windows 10 Upgrade under Windows 8.1 OS

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1

I have over 171 updates to do (under Windows 8.1) but I can't launch them because every time I click on the Install Updates button, Windows 10 Download is starting, and I don't want it.

I took care to remove all GWX stuff, following some procedures found on the internet and here in this site.  Now, I don't have any GWX entry in the registry and the GWX process is not in the Task Manager.  I also checked into the Task Scheduler and nothing is there in regard to GWX.

Every single KBxxxxxxx that should be hidden in Windows Updates have been hidden successfully.

KB3035583, KB3022345, KB3068708, KB3075249, KB3080149, KB2990214, KB3012973, KB2952664, KB2976978.

In addition, I have successfully removed the GWX icon (and process) in the notification area using another procedure.

So I'm pretty sure that the problem is under Windows Update itself which is launching the Windows 10 Upgrade by itself when I click the Install Updates button.  I was not able to fix this problem yet, tying many things but unfortunately without success.

Keys inside the registry have been also adjusted to not allow OS upgrade.

I'm still looking to find a solution on this, many hours have been spent so far.....

Comment: stop WU service, rename the folder C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution to C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.old, now search for new updates and hide here Win10

Answer (score 0):

When you search for windows updates, it will give you the "Start installing the newest version of Windows now" with <kbd>Get started</kbd> button. A text line below will tell you `Show all available updates`. If you press that, you can then select which updates you want to install, and thus remove the checkbox for the windows 10 upgrade.

[image]

Additionally, you can choose to hide the upgrade so the above screen won't show again and Windows update works as before again.

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you, but Windows Update don't show "Upgrade to Windows 10" right now, it shows "Downloading Windows 10" as soon as click on Install Updates, the only button I can do is "Stop Download".  The "Upgrade to Windows 10" update is not there at all in my updates.  Even the KBxxxxxx I listed in my question are not there because I hidden them.

Should I wait until the Windows 10 Download completed?

Comment: Ah, so you already started the upgrade process which basically overrides windows updates. You can try restarting the Windows Update services.

Comment: I did but the same problem happens.  And yes I think the download process has started but it only starts when I click "Install Selected Updates" even if no Windows 10 related updates are not there. Still looking for a solution!

Comment: I'm not sure you can abort this at this point, unless you are willing to wait until 29th of July. At that point this update will no longer be available as the entire upgrade will be stopped and a valid license has to be bought. If you can't wait 20 more days, you can always go ahead with the upgrade, and once done, roll back. You won't loose your settings. Only one or two programs may have to be installed again if they are incompatible with windows 10.